# how to remove one sentence with two specific initial words

Tags: python, dataframe

[image]

I have a dataframe that contains a news dataset. I want to remove one sentence with two specific initial words, i.e. "baca juga:, .... laga." for example. Have an idea how to do it?

This is additional information if u need it.

[image]

Comment: can you post the head of the `df`, is that screenshot just one column?

Comment: @ksooklall yes, that is just screenshot of one column

Answer (score 0):

You can try df.loc to find it and then change it to be blank:

```
df.loc[df['news'].astype(str).str.contains(r'(?:baca juga)', regex=True), 'news']
```

and if that works, you can set it to blank with = ''

Comment: how does this remove the sentence? Doesn''t it only remove those 2 words

Comment: `Series([], Name: news, dtype: object)` I got this error

Comment: `berita = pd.DataFrame(berita, columns=['news'])
berita = berita.loc[berita['news'].astype(str).str.contains(r'^baca juga', regex=True), 'news']
berita` I try like this

Comment: well, you have to change "news" to the actual column name you have. Try that, it should work

Comment: My column name is 'news' too. I have tried it. But I got 'Series([], Name: news, dtype: object)'

Answer (score 0):

Using regex, find the sentence then replace it with a blank space

I don't see baca juga in your example but assuming its in one of the rows

```
import re
df['news'].map(lambda x: re.sub(r'(baca juga[^.]+.)', '', x))
```

Explanation

- `baca juga` start with this
- `[^.]` this matches any character that's not a period
- `+.` keep going until a reaching a period and remove that period as well

Example

```
input_df
                                                news
0  dskfl fsdg wer. baca juga: fgads awr yut. dfaw...
1          rwepu fsan apsj lis. fja jp ios jos lfslt
```

```
Output_df
0           dskfl fsdg wer.  dfaw top fapw asf
1    rwepu fsan apsj lis. fja jp ios jos lfslt
```

Comment: yes you never provided the column name so i used `col` in place

Comment: can you provide `df.head()` for me to help you further

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UTBbDfE1up3a8SU4pmIZjrTS166Ytwip/view?usp=sharing

Comment: the result is still contains "baca juga, …." https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UGt9cPnbA-I-gvgxS_trPjsWTps56vLM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204014/discussion-between-novvv-and-ksooklall).